# Error while typing "gem install rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Can anybody please help me to resolve this error.Actually i am trying to install ruby-1.9.3 and rails-4 in windows-XP 32 bit.When i followed the below steps and got some error.

Steps:

```
1-I installed ruby version-1.9.3
2-I installed the proper devkit and gave path(C:\Ruby193\devkit) to extract it.
3-I typed gem update --system in CMD.
4-When i typed the command gem install rails in cmd it gave some error.
```

Error:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20141229-2792-pk1no5.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make  clean
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.
1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/js
on-1.8.1/gem_make.out
```

Please help me to resolve this error.Thanks

Comment: And the codeline in `Makefile:165` contains ...?

Comment: `gem install json` what it gives?

Comment: Use RailsInstaller.

http://railsinstaller.org/en

Comment: No,same error is showing. any other solution please share here.

Comment: did you init & install devkit?

Comment: Thanks all..I have resolved this error.

Comment: @subhra can you post your solution please